# Looking for something like Calibre for managing my ebooks and sending them to my ereader

Tags: ebooks

I have calibre but it's not working properly with my new Sony PRS-T3 reader. It is not sending them to the reader in the 'series' I have created. I want them nicely organised on my reader. So I want something that works like that and is free. Any suggestions? All the ones I have found either cost or don't do what I want.

Comment: Have you thought of raising a ticket on Calibre https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre if there isn't one already?

Comment: He said they are no longer updating support stuff for the Sony ereaders.